# VBA: why I cannot use "=" to transfer data from one sheet to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use `"="` operator to transfer data from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" because it is fast. However, the following code doesn't work:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").range(cells(1, 1),cells(1,5)).value = Sheets("Sheet1")
.range(cells(1, 1),cells(1,5)).value
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Range` and `Cells` are not fully qualified, then they will be taken from `ActiveSheet`.

So the code line

```
Sheets("Sheet2").range(cells(1, 1),cells(1,5)).value = Sheets("Sheet1").range(cells(1, 1),cells(1,5)).value
```

is the same as

```
Sheets("Sheet2").range(ActiveSheet.cells(1, 1),ActiveSheet.cells(1,5)).value = Sheets("Sheet1").range(ActiveSheet.cells(1, 1),ActiveSheet.cells(1,5)).value
```

This fails because either the cells of `Sheet2` or the cells of `Sheet1` cannot be from `ActiveSheet`. Maybe both are not if neither `Sheet2` nor `Sheet1` is the active sheet.

So we must fully qualify the cells:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 5)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5)).Value
```

Better we are using  `Worksheet` variables for better readability:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(1, 5)).Value = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(1, 5)).Value
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It does work if you do it cell by cell and loop through them.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").cells(1, 1).value = Sheets("Sheet1").cells(1,1).value
```

I am not sure if you can use = on a range but will have a look.You could copy and paste a range however.